# How to add the random number value in swift

Tags: swift, random

I want a label to display 3 random numbers from 1 -10. Each time the displayed number will change randomly, and the number will appear in the label in 1 second before change to other number. After displaying 3 random number, it will give the total value of 3 numbers it appeared.

For example: when I click button, the label give me a first number, 1 second later, the label give me the second number, 1 second later the label give me the third number then label stop and give me the total number (number1 + number2 + number3 )in the other result label.

Could you give me some clues?

Comment: NSTimer for doing something every second, arc4random_uniform() for random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would do it.

```
        class Example: UIViewController {
        var run = true
        var timer: NSTimer!
        var number = 1 
        var array: [Int]!
         @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
         @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
          func switchNumberOnLabel() {
           var appendthing = Int.random()
            label.text = "\(appendthing)"
           array.append(appendthing)
            number += 1
            if number == 3 {
           timer.invalidate()
           resultLabel.text = "\(addArrayElements(array))"
}
        }

         func addArrayElements(array: [Int])->Int {
         return array[0] + array[1] + array[2]
}
          @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
                if run {
                timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "switchNumberOnLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                var randomnumber = Int.random()
                array.append(randomnumber)
                label.text = "\(randomnumber)"
                run = false
                }

        }



        }

        extension Int {
           static func random()-> Int {
            return Int(arc4random() % UInt32(9)) + 1

        }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Epic..Sorry for send you a ThAnks too late :)